# PHP Understanding my var_dump

Tags: php, json, api, curl

I have a PHP script that does almost all of what I want to. I am extracting several bits of information from an API and preparing a CSV document- the document gets created just fine, but several of the columns are blank and I'm not sure how to call them from the object(stdClass) I am getting in my vardump. I am trying to get the following indexes from each of the numkey objects below:

1. name
2. VariantCustomIds->id
3. updated_at

I'm really struggling with my var_dump of a decoded JSON. Here is what the JSON response is from the API in question:

---

```
{
"623587": {
  "caption": "",
  "created_at": "2015-06-30T17:59:24+00:00",
  "deleted": "0",
  "id": "623587",
  "links": {
    "VariantCustomIds": [
      {
        "id": "108601807"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "SKU",
  "updated_at": "2015-06-30T17:59:24+00:00"
},
"840664": {
  "caption": "",
  "created_at": "2015-09-21T15:04:18+00:00",
  "deleted": "0",
  "id": "840664",
  "links": {
    "VariantCustomIds": [
      {
        "id": "144012064"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "Headband Style",
  "updated_at": "2015-09-21T15:04:18+00:00"
},
"840684": {
  "caption": "",
  "created_at": "2015-09-21T15:04:18+00:00",
  "deleted": "0",
  "id": "840684",
  "links": {
    "VariantCustomIds": [
      {
        "id": "144012074"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "Ink Type",
  "updated_at": "2015-09-21T15:04:18+00:00"
},
"840694": {
  "caption": "",
  "created_at": "2015-09-21T15:04:18+00:00",
  "deleted": "0",
  "id": "840694",
  "links": {
    "VariantCustomIds": [
      {
        "id": "144012084"
      }
    ]
  },
  "name": "Fabric Type",
  "updated_at": "2015-09-21T15:04:18+00:00"
}
}
```

---

I pass this through a json_decode function in PHP, and here is the var_dump I get:

---

```
 object(stdClass)#1308 (1) { ["623587"]=> object(stdClass)#1310 (7) { ["caption"]=> string(0) "" ["created_at"]=> string(25) "2015-06-30T17:59:24+00:00" ["deleted"]=> string(1) "0" ["id"]=> string(6) "623587" ["links"]=> object(stdClass)#1309 (1) { ["VariantCustomIds"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1303 (1) { ["id"]=> string(9) "108601798" } } } ["name"]=> string(3) "SKU" ["updated_at"]=> string(25) "2015-06-30T17:59:24+00:00" } }
```

I have tried doing a for each loop on this, but there is only 1 object when I do that. I have tried calling $myVariable->id, $myVariable->links, and $myVariable->name. All of these come back with a NULL when I pass them through var_dump().

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Erhhh... what is your specific issue?

Comment: I have no idea how to call the the three specific indexes I mentioned in the post:

name
VariantCustomIds->id
updated_at

When I call them they come back NULL when they are definitely not NULL in the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [json_decode documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). There is second (optinal) parameter which tells json_decode to return asoc array. So your code should look like:

```
$decoded = json_decode($jsonString, true);
```

Answer (score 4):

Just follow the brackets/braces, remembering that in JS, `{}` is an object, and `[]` is an array:

```
json = {
|      | "623587": {
|      |           |    "caption": "",
|      |           |    "created_at": "2015-06-30T17:59:24+00:00",
|      |           |    "deleted": "0",
|      |           |    "id": "623587",
|      |           |    "links": {
|      |           |    |        |   "VariantCustomIds": [
|      |           |    |        |   |                   |    {
|      |           |    |        |   |                   |    |    "id": "108601807"
|      |           |    |        |   |                   |    |    |
$obj  ->  623587    ->  links   ->   variantcustomids    [0]  ->   id
```

So your final PHP path, using proper access methods and capitalization

```
$obj[623587]->links->VariantCustomIds[0]->id
```

Comment: When I call the number index (which is not constant for all of the items I want to call) it gives me this error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'

Comment: Zoran gave me the answer I was looking for the whole time- I wasn't decoding as an asoc array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know, you've solved. But you could go to StdClass objects approach as well:

```
<?php

$sample = file_get_contents('http://host/api/sample.json');
$data = json_decode($sample);

foreach ($data as $id => $object) {

    $name       = $object->name;        
    $id         = $object->links->VariantCustomIds[0]->id; #OR $id = $id       
    $updated_at = $object->updated_at;
}
```

Comment: Interesting- I know very little about actual object oriented programming. I found another post today that explained to me that arrays can be called using $variable['key'] and that objects are $variable->key and that was my first time really understanding how they were functionally different. Personally I prefer the asoc array method because I find it easier to read.